# (2027, 'Malformed packet') packet issue with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, amazon-aurora

Environment

- Amazon RDS Aurora - 2.03.1
- MySQL Innodb - 5.7.12
- SQLAlchemy - 1.2.18
- Python - 3.6.7

I have this table

```
class Users(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
      id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(String(64))
    email = Column(String(64))
    first_name = Column(String(100))
    last_name = Column(String(100))
    mobile = Column(String(100))
    last_org_session = Column(ForeignKey("organizations.id"))
```

I am using the `session.query` version of querying.

```
updated_by_user_query = select([Users.id, Users.first_name, Users.last_name]).where(
         Users.id == obj["updated_by"]
     )
     updated_by_user = session.execute(updated_by_user_query).first()
```

This issue is that when tested locally it works.
But when tested on a staging environment, it raises a malformed packet error issue.

I have confirmed that localhost and staging are using the same environment and database.

Any ideas what I should do?

Comment: SQLAlchemy does not do the actual talking to databases, but uses what ever DB-API driver library you are using. Try upgrading that, if possible.

Comment: I have tried updating the packages above(incouding DB-API driver library) but that still didn't work. I will be looking into the actual MySQL server next.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Tried upgrading my `mysqlclient` driver but to no avail.